# SecurityException: Given caller package com.android.settings is not running in process ProcessRecord

Tags: android, settings, activitygroup

I use ActivityGroup for TAB UI, and one Tab content is Android Settings view,
I used this method to embed into:

```
final Intent settings = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS);
settings.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
Window subActivity = getLocalActivityManager().startActivity("SubActivity_Settings", settings);
vSettings = subActivity.getDecorView();
```

And it works well in Android 2.3.3, but now I have to move to Android 4.0,
Unfortunately it doesn't work with the exception like the below:

05-13 07:02:36.242: E/AndroidRuntime(1118): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.android.settings/com.android.settings.Settings}: java.lang.SecurityException: Given caller package com.android.settings is not running in process ProcessRecord{414674b0 1118:com.gul.desktop/10040}

Can buddies tell me how to solve it, and what't the ProcessRecord?

Comment: me too facing same problem ? got any solutions for this ? thank you in advance, please help me

Answer (score 3):

> I use ActivityGroup for TAB UI

That is officially deprecated as of API Level 11.

> And it works well in Android 2.3.3

Not really. It *looks* like it "works well", but the user cannot actually change any of the settings that your own UI could not change. Android 4.0 merely tightens up the security even further.

> Can buddies tell me how to solve it

Write your own UI for modifying the settings, for those settings that normal SDK apps can modify. Or, launch the Settings app via `startActivity()`, using `Intent` actions found on `android.provider.Settings`.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this exception because in your **manifest** file you may have register your activity twice or more than one time.

for ex:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name"> 
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^
     <intent-filter> 
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
         <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
     </intent-filter>
 </activity>

<activity android:name=".MainActivity"> </activity>
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Remove unwanted lines....
Hope this will work for you..!

Comment: I checked the xml configuration you mentioned, but doesn't work. Someone tell me because the Settings does not run under the same UID with my app, I guess Android 4.0 strenghtens the security rules, but I'm not sure.